# Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: xml

I am new to XML and getting the below error:

> Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same
>   entity

**Input XML:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
<test>
<access1>113AL</access1>
<access2>119AL</access2>
</test>
<test>
<access2>115AL<s/access2>
<access3>116AL</access3>
</test>
<test>
<access4>118AL</access4>
<access5>119AL</access5>
</test>
<copies>
<test2>
<access>113AL</access>
<Copy>Y</Copy>
</test2>
<test2>
<access>113AX</access>
<Copy>N</Copy>
</test2>
</copies>
</root>
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your XML is not well-formed.  **In general, this error indicates that something is wrong with the range of the start and end tags.**

In particular in your case, you have a stray `s` in one of the closing `access2` tags:

```
    <access2>115AL<s/access2>
```

Here is your XML with the problem resolved; it is now well-formed (and indented to improve readability):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
  <test>
    <access1>113AL</access1>
    <access2>119AL</access2>
  </test>
  <test>
    <access2>115AL</access2>
    <access3>116AL</access3>
  </test>
  <test>
    <access4>118AL</access4>
    <access5>119AL</access5>
  </test>
  <copies>
    <test2>
      <access>113AL</access>
      <Copy>Y</Copy>
    </test2>
    <test2>
      <access>113AX</access>
      <Copy>N</Copy>
    </test2>
  </copies>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your `xml` is well formed, as fixed in kjhughes answer, you can always run `xmllint` to prettify it as:

```
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ cat foo.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
<test>
<access1>113AL</access1>
<access2>119AL</access2>
</test>
<test>
<access2>115AL</access2>
<access3>116AL</access3>
</test>
<test>
<access4>118AL</access4>
<access5>119AL</access5>
</test>
<copies>
<test2>
<access>113AL</access>
<Copy>Y</Copy>
</test2>
<test2>
<access>113AX</access>
<Copy>N</Copy>
</test2>
</copies>
</root>
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ xmllint --format foo.xml --output foo.xml
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ 
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$ cat foo.xml 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<root>
  <test>
    <access1>113AL</access1>
    <access2>119AL</access2>
  </test>
  <test>
    <access2>115AL</access2>
    <access3>116AL</access3>
  </test>
  <test>
    <access4>118AL</access4>
    <access5>119AL</access5>
  </test>
  <copies>
    <test2>
      <access>113AL</access>
      <Copy>Y</Copy>
    </test2>
    <test2>
      <access>113AX</access>
      <Copy>N</Copy>
    </test2>
  </copies>
</root>
[nsaunders@rolly ~]$
```

Just as an FYI.

Of course, `xmllint` is primarily for validating a document.

Answer (score 0):

I spend a lot of time on this still, I cannot able to find file where this issue is available and finally, This work for me

```
android {
    buildTypes {
        release {
            shrinkResources false
        }
    }
}
```

*Note: If necessary, you can disable resource shrinking by adding*