# Strings.xml:18:50: Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I am new to XML and getting the below error:

C:\Users\Hammad Shah\RevenuesAndExpences\app\src\main\res\values\strings.xml:18:50: Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity.

**XML**:

Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
  you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
  You may obtain a copy of the License at

```
  https://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
```

Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
  distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
  WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
  See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
  limitations under the License.
  -->

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116985/error-xml-document-structures-must-start-and-end-within-the-same-entity

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error: XML document structures must start and end within the same entity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37116985/error-xml-document-structures-must-start-and-end-within-the-same-entity)

Comment: paste ur String.xml code here